# mysql jdbc not batching queries even after rewriteBatchedStatements = true

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I've been reading all over the internet + stackoverflow on why jdbc batch update is so slow. Looks like the proper fix is to set `rewriteBatchedStatements = true` in the connection string.  But I cant seem to get it to work for me.

I am using springboot and spring-jdbc
Ive set `rewriteBatchedStatements = true` in my  application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://RDS_URL.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/DATABASE?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

I have also set a breakpoint to verify that the `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true` is reflected in code

I have general_log set to true and when watching the logs I see that the inserts are not being properly batched

This is what my sql string looks like

`private static String INSERT_USER_TO_GROUP_SQL = "INSERT INTO users (groupId, phoneNumber, accountId, source) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";`

The lines in the logs all look like this

`45 Query   INSERT INTO users (groupId, phoneNumber, accountId, source) VALUES('49', '99999999999', '123', 'web')`

My java code to do the batch insert is

```
executor.submit(() -> {
  jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT_USER_TO_GROUP_SQL, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
      Subscriber subscriber = subscribers.get(i);
      ps.setString(1, subscriberGroup.getGroupId());
      ps.setString(2, subscriber.getPhoneNumber());
      ps.setString(3, accountId);
      ps.setString(4, subscriberGroup.getSource());
    }

    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
      return subscribers.size();
    }

  }); // end BatchPreparedStatementSetter lambda class
}); // end thread
```

Here is a snippet from the method `batchUpdate` looks like this, as you can see it calls addBatch(), then finally executeBatch()

```
for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
    pss.setValues(ps, i);
    if (ipss != null && ipss.isBatchExhausted(i)) {
        break;
    }
    ps.addBatch();
}
return ps.executeBatch();
```

Here is the table i am inserting into

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupId` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `phoneNumber` (`phoneNumber`,`groupId`,`accountId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21677 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

ALSO I have even tried not relying on jdbc.batchUpdate() and doing it myself. With still no luck

```
    Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
    connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USER_TO_GROUP_SQL);

    preparedStatement.setString(1, "1");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "2");
    preparedStatement.setString(3, "3");
    preparedStatement.setString(4, "4");
    preparedStatement.addBatch();

    preparedStatement.setString(1, "11");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "22");
    preparedStatement.setString(3, "33");
    preparedStatement.setString(4, "44");
    preparedStatement.addBatch();

    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
```

ALSO I tried to rule out issues with prepared statements so I tried just hard coding queries. Still no luck.

```
Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO users (groupId, phoneNumber, accountId, source) VALUES('1', '2', '3', '4')");
statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO users (groupId, phoneNumber, accountId, source) VALUES('11', '22', '33', '44')");
statement.executeBatch();
```

This is the version of jdbc in my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Im expecting this parameter to speed up the insert and for the logs to show a properly batched insert statement. Most SO articles show people just setting `rewritebatchedstatements = true` in the url and it works.

Comment: Please read this, especially the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Then please [edit] your question to provide more information.  In the meantime, please figure out whether you have autocommit turned on, or whether you are wrapping multiple `INSERT` statements in `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` blocks in your SQL.

Comment: Thanks for that. I edited the title as i'm not really concerned about the particular query performance, it should be quick as it's just an insert, and I dont think this is a typical, "why is my query slow" question
Im more interested in why the rewritebatchedstatements = true isnt being respected and properly batching the inserts. Ive added the table structure and autocommit and its currently turned to on

Comment: Where's your code that uses the `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()` methods? The performance gain from a rewrite comes from using a batch to do a multirow insert, and thereby cuttting down on the number of implicit `COMMIT` operations performed by the database server.  Are you calling `addBatch()` a whole mess of times before you call `executeBatch()`?   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes I am. Ive added a snippet of the implementation of jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() which I am using in my first example, that method calls addBatch() and executeBatch(). Also Ive added another snippet of what I've tried, where I call addBatch() and executeBatch() explicitly without using the built in JdbcTemplate method batchUpdate()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For others having the issue of jdbcTemplate connection url not honoring `rewriteBatchedStatements = true` Check your `mysql-connector-java` version in your `pom.xml`

At the time of writing this question I had

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Since my batch writes were happening one by one it appears that version 5.1.9 doesn't support batch updates, and falls back as noted in the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter-)

> batchUpdate() -- Will fall back to separate updates on a single Statement if the JDBC driver does not support batch updates.

Bumping this to version 5.1.18 gave me proper batch updates, verified in mysql general log.

Also a bug I ran into which might save others some time. In version 5.1.23, when you configure the db url to include `profileSQL=true` which I imagine most do, there's a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70677) with the driver and profileSQL.